# What does $u+(du/dx)\Delta x$ mean? in mechanical equation

Tags: differentiation, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, variational-calculus, displacement

what does $u+(du/dx)\Delta x$ mean?

[image]

Comment: It is the Taylor expansion of $u(x)$

Comment: @FellowTraveller thank you, can you explain more detail? f'(u)*(x-u)+f(u) means u+(du/dx)delta(x)?

Comment: @Heewon, in addition to what Fellow Traveller stated, note that the function $u(x)$ has been linearized about a specific point.  Assuming that matrix mathematics is being used, this is a useful technique because matrices only work on linear equations.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series is the polynomial expansion of functions of certain kind. More details can be looked up [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series). What this says is that if we know the value of a function $f(x)$ and all it’s derivatives at a point $x_0$ then we can express the value of the function at any point $x+h$ by using:

$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+\frac{h}{1!}f’(x)\big|_{x_0}+ \frac{h^2}{2!}f’’(x)\big|_{x_0}+\dots$$

Now if we have a small $h$ that means we are looking at a point sufficiently close to the original point then we can approximate the function to:

$$f(x_0+h)\approx f(x_0)+hf’(x)\big|_{x_0}$$

Now $h$ is just the difference between your two $x$ points, thus we can rewrite it into

$$f(x_0+h)\approx f(x_0)+\Delta x\frac{df(x)}{dx}\bigg|_{x_0}$$

In your case, $f$ is $u$ and that’s it.

Comment: Oh nice explain, Thank you for your prompt response! Have a nice day :)